# How to extract data from the XML file includes the XSL content?

Tags: xml, xslt, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have an XML file. In that file some dates are coming from the XSL file. So how can I get those dates. So basically I am using Pentaho and that read XML file. My XML file contains dates which is in another XSL file.
So how can I get the dates from XSL using XML?

Comment: Please provide some code showing what you got so far.

Comment: I am not getting any fields , because that fields are coming from the XSL file . So when I opened XML file in the web , it is showing that content but when I searched it I didn't find . So I searched that into the XSL file and found it . So I didn't write any code for that . I need a way to fetch those fields . Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Please add a small sample of your XML + XSL